# 3 table count query mysql

Tags: sql, mysql

I have 3 tables

```
products [which contains data related to products]
    productid (int)
    name (varchar)
    price (float)

sales [which contains data related to sales]
    salesid (int)
    productid (int)
    time (datetime)

links [which contains data related to links from products]
    linkid (int)
    productid (int)
    link (text)
```

I need output as such

```
ProductID   Name   TotalSales    TotalLinkAvailable
    1       ABCD       10               12
    1       EFGH       7                25
```

How can I achieve this using single query?

Thanks

**EDIT**

I have tried the following query which did not work:

```
select p.name,count(s.salesid) as Sales, count(l.linkid) as Links 
from products p 
left join sales s on p.productid=s.productid 
left join links l on p.products=l.productid 
group by p.productid
```

Comment: With `JOIN`, `GROUP BY` and `COUNT`. I'm just too lazy to write the query right now.

Comment: @Bobby: I tried following query     select p.name,count(s.salesid) as Sales ,count(l.linkid) as Links
 from products p left join sales s on p.productid=s.productid
 left join links l on p.products=l.productid 
group by p.productid               but it's not working

Comment: Please always tell us in the question what you've already tried, it helps as alot to help you.

Comment: @Bobby: next time I will surely mention what I have tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT p.productid AS ProductID, p.name AS Name, COUNT(s.salesid) AS TotalSales, COUNT(l.linkid) AS TotalLinkAvailable
FROM products AS p
LEFT JOIN sales AS s ON s.productid = p.productid
LEFT JOIN links AS l ON l.productid = p.productid
GROUP BY p.productid, p.name
```

Assuming that there is a typo regarding the ProductID in the second row of your exemplary query result.

Comment: @I-M-JM - you list product 1 with 2 different names in your example.

Comment: I just added count(distinct(s.salesid)) and it worked, thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
select p.productid, p.name, count(s.salesid) as TotalSales, count(l.linkid) as TotalLinkAvailable
    from products p
        left join sales s
            on p.productid = s.productid
        left join links l
            on p.productid = l.productid
    group by p.productid, p.name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select p.pname,count(s.salesid) as Sales ,count(l.linkid) as Links
 from products p left join sales s on p.productid=s.productid
 left join links l on p.products=l.productid 
group by p.productid
```